# What is an exclamation point in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

In a schema file that I have I noticed there are exclamation marks after some types, like

```
# Information on an account relationship
type AccountEdge {
  cursor: String!
  node: Account!
}
```

What do these mean? I can't find anything about it in the documentation or through googling

Answer (score 162, accepted):

That means that the field is non-nullable.

See more info in [Graphql - Schemas and Types](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#:%7E:text=means%20that%20the%20field%20is,those%20with%20an%20exclamation%20mark)

Comment: This took longer to find out than I expected. Even the GraphQL cheatsheets and the Prisma and Apollo docs didn't seem to mention that explicitly.

Comment: Documentation link with nifty highlighting (works in Chrome): https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#:~:text=means%20that%20the%20field%20is,those%20with%20an%20exclamation%20mark.

Comment: @Purplejacket  That's fancy, I updated the link in the answer! :)

Comment: makes sense right? if `?` often means nullable, then `!` would mean non-nullable

Answer (score 54):

From the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Type-System.Non-Null):

> By default, all types in GraphQL are nullable; the null value is a valid response for all of the above types. To declare a type that disallows null, the GraphQL Non‐Null type can be used. This type wraps an underlying type, and this type acts identically to that wrapped type, with the exception that null is not a valid response for the wrapping type. A trailing exclamation mark is used to denote a field that uses a Non‐Null type like this: name: String!.

In other words, types in GraphQL are nullable by default. An exclamation point after a type specifically designates that type as non-nullable.

This has different implications depending on where the type is used.

#### Output

When non-null is applied to the type of a **field**, it means that if the server resolves that field to `null`, the response will fail validation. You may still receive a partial response, as long as the error does not [propagate all the way up to the root](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Errors-and-Non-Nullability).

For example, given a schema like:

```
type Query {
  user: User
}

type User {
  id: ID!
}
```

Here the `id` field is non-null. By marking the field as non-null, we are effectively *guaranteeing* we will never return null for this field. If the server does return null, then it's an indication that something went terribly wrong and we want to throw a validation error.

#### Input

When non-null is applied to the type of an **input**, like an argument, input object field or a variable, it makes that input required. For example:

```
type Query {
  getUser(id: ID!, status: Status): User
}
```

Here, the `id` argument is non-null. If we request the `getUser` field, we will always have to provide the `id` argument for it. On the other hand, because the `status` argument is nullable, it's optional and can be omitted. This applies to variables as well:

```
query MyQuery ($foo: ID!) {
  getUser(id: $foo)
}
```

Because the `$foo` variable is non-null, when you send the query, it cannot be omitted and it's value cannot equal `null`.

#### A special note on variable types

Because the `id` field is a non-null `ID` (i.e. `ID!`) type in our example, any variable we pass it must **also** be a non-null `ID`. If our `$foo` variable was a nullable `ID`, we could not pass it to the `id` argument. The opposite, however, is not true. If an argument is nullable, you **can** pass it a non-null variable.

In other words:

```
+----------+----------+--------+
| Argument | Variable | Valid? |
+----------+----------+--------+
| String   | String   |   ✅   |
| String   | String!  |   ✅   |
| String!  | String   |   ❌   |
| String!  | String!  |   ✅   |
+----------+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

## TLDR: it means throw an error if value is null

User tried to send `null` for an input field which has `!` -> instant error response

Server tried to return `null` for a field that has `!` -> return an error instead

## Why would you add `!` if it only throws errors ?

If you know that a `null` in the input would crash your server then better to throw the error early.

If you know that a `null` in the response would crash your client then better to throw the error early.

I'm using "crash" broadly to refer to all possible bugs or volnurabilities that could occur.

## Example

Schema:

```
type Query
{
    data(input: InputType!): ResponseType!
}

input InputType
{
    inputField: String!
}

type ResponseType
{
    field: String!
}
```

Input Variables which are OK:

```json
{
    input: {
        inputField: "sample text"
    }
}
```

Input Variables which will throw errors:

```json
// error: inputField is null
{
    input: {
        inputField: null
    }
}

// error: inputField is null (because it's missing)
{
    input: {
    }
}

// error: input is null
{
    input:  null 
}

// error: input is null (because it's missing)
{
}
```

Server Response which is OK:

```json
{
    data: {
        field: "sample text"
    }
}
```

Server Responses which will throw errors:

```json
// error: field is null
{
    data: {
        field: null
    }
}

// error: field is null (because it's missing)
{
    data: {
    }
}

// error: data is null
{
    data: null
}
```