# What is the exclamation mark for after the variable?

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to understand the [snipppet](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers) from graph ql appollo tutorial. What is the exclamation mark for after the variable? ID!

```
  query GetLaunchById($id: ID!) {
      launch(id: $id) {
        id
        rocket {
          id
          type
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [What is an exclamation point in graphql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684231/what-is-an-exclamation-point-in-graphql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it's non-nullable.

See : https://graphql.org/learn/schema/