# Getting Error Variable "$name" of required type "String!" was not provided. on firing Graphql request from React-Apollo

Tags: javascript, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphiql

Here's the 1st error on component rendering:

POST http://localhost:4000/graphql 500 (Internal Server Error)

[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$name" of required type "String!" was not provided.

The 2nd error on firing query(submitting form):

```
this.props.movieByName is not a function...
```

Here's the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {HashLink as Link} from 'react-router-hash-link' 
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import {flowRight as compose} from 'lodash'
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";


const movieByName = gql`
  query SomeName($name: String!){
    movieByName(name: $name){
      name
      genre
      year
    }
  }
`

class Header extends Component {
  state = {
  name: '',
  genre: '',
  year: ''
}

searchSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  this.props.movieByName({
   variables: {
     name: event.target.value
   }
 })
 console.log(this.props)}

 render(){
  return (
  <div className="topnav">
    <a className="logo" href="/">Movie Maker</a>
    <div className="search-container">
      <form onSubmit={this.searchSubmit}>
        <Link smooth to="#form">Add Movies</Link>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" 
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({name: e.target.value})}/>
        <button type="submit"><i className="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
);}}

export default graphql(movieByName)(Header)
```

Comment: Hi mohdraqif, welcome to StackOverflow! 

Answer (score 3):

#### What does this error mean?

- Your graphql schema is expecting a variable called `$name`.
- That variable needs to be of type `String` and it cannot be undefined or null (it's [required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684231/what-is-an-exclamation-point-in-graphql))

#### Debugging information

- What's the value of `event.target.value` when your `searchSubmit` executes? I suspect that it's actually undefined

#### Solution

- Call your query with the name value defined in the state. Because you update the state within the inputs `onChange` handler, the most up to date value will be stored there

  ```
  this.props.movieByName({
    variables: {
      name: this.state.name
    }
  })
  ```

Comment: Sir, you're right. It was undefined. But the error: variable not found still persists and shows on component rendering. Also on firing query, even with variables object, it shows movieByname is not a function. A little help there too.

Comment: I suspect there might be something wrong with how graphql and the component are wired together in this part `export default graphql(movieByName)(Header)`

Comment: I am surprised that this component is trying to execute the query, but it is not the one that is rendering the results. Could you update your question with what you are trying to do within each component that you are using? If you could put up a https://codesandbox.io/dashboard that shows how to reproduce your error, that would be very helpful 