# Why ! after String in graphql?

Tags: ecmascript-6, graphql

What is the purpose of appending ! after String param in graphql methods.

`query method($param: String!)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an exclamation point in GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684231/what-is-an-exclamation-point-in-graphql)

Answer (score 0):

This modifier means that the type cannot be null.

> String! means that the field is non-nullable, meaning that the GraphQL service promises to always give you a value when you query this field. In the type language, we'll represent those with an exclamation mark

> The Non-Null type modifier can also be used when defining arguments for a field, which will cause the GraphQL server to return a validation error if a null value is passed as that argument, whether in the GraphQL string or in the variables.

https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#type-system

[What is an exclamation point in GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684231/what-is-an-exclamation-point-in-graphql)